# How to use Weaviate's admin console locally?

Tags: weaviate

Is there a local admin console for Weaviate? I can see that https://console.weaviate.cloud/ allows you to connect to a local instance, but I would prefer a local one. Is there any?

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible but I would encourage you to open an issue to request this feature here:

https://github.com/weaviate/weaviate

Comment: Seems like there is one issue open already - https://github.com/weaviate/weaviate/issues/3246